# Why is my version of python scitools 0.9.0 missing scitools.filetable?

Tags: python

The scitools documentation lists dozens of submodules, including the one I want: scitools.filetable. Yet in my installation (Mac 10.5.8, python 2.7) most of these are missing. All that remain are:

```
scitools.FloatComparison  
scitools.StringFunction   
scitools.author           
scitools.basics           
scitools.configdata       
scitools.debug 
scitools.easyviz          
scitools.errorcheck       
scitools.globaldata       
scitools.misc             
scitools.numpyutils
scitools.numpytools
scitools.std
scitools.sys
scitools.version
```

When I first noticed this problem today, I was using scitools 0.8, so I upgraded to 0.9.0 with:

```
$ sudo pip install scitools --upgrade
```

The install was successful (according to pip). filetable is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply that they're not all loaded by default:

```
>>> import scitools
>>> scitools.filetable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filetable'
>>> dir(scitools)
['FloatComparison', 'StringFunction', '__acknowledgments__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_numpyload', 'author', 'basics', 'configdata', 'debug', 'easyviz', 'errorcheck', 'globaldata', 'misc', 'numpytools', 'numpyutils', 'std', 'sys', 'version']
>>> import scitools.filetable
>>> scitools.filetable
<module 'scitools.filetable' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scitools/filetable.pyc'>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. By the way, I worked around my problem by using numpy.loadtxt and numpy.savetxt instead.